# Configure secured websockets using Apache httpd 2.4.6 and Tomcat 8

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, websocket, atmosphere

I'm trying to configure websockets using httpd proxy and reverse proxy but it doesn't seem to work. If I use directly the tomcat server everything is fine, if I call it through apache httpd, the response status is **200**. This means apache httpd cannot interpret the websocket request and switch the protocol, right?

This is my httpd config for my app:

```
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so

Listen 443 https


SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-pass-dialog

SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/run/httpd/sslcache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin

SSLCryptoDevice builtin


<VirtualHost 10.224.130.50:80>

    ServerName myhost
    Redirect permanent / https://myhost/

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.224.130.50:443>

    ServerName myhost
    ErrorLog logs/myhost.error.log
    CustomLog logs/myhost.access.log common

    ProxyPass /ws/       wss://localhost:8443/ws/ retry=0
    ProxyPassReverse /ws/ wss://localhost:8443/ws/ retry=0

    ProxyPass / https://myhost:8443/ connectiontimeout=600 timeout=1200
    ProxyPassReverse / https://myhost:8443/


    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
    SSLProxyEngine on
        SSLProxyVerify none 
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
    SSLCertificateFile    "/etc/pki/tls/certs/myhost.cer"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/private/myhost.key"

</VirtualHost>
```

And this is the Connector config for Apache Tomcat:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
           keystoreFile="/root/.keystore"
           keystorePass="password" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem may be slashes:

> NOTE: Pay strict attention to the slashes "/" or lack thereof!
> WebSocket url endpoint

`ProxyPass /ws/ wss://localhost:8443/ws`

`ProxyPassReverse /ws/ wss://localhost:8443/ws`

More information here:
[tunneling-secure-websocket-connections-with-apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468154/tunneling-secure-websocket-connections-with-apache)

Comment: Sorry, I tried with and without slashes... still doesn't work... I tried to follow the docs but nothing comes out... the problem is because sometimes I get error 200, this means httpd does the redirect but not in a proper way, right?

Comment: Can you show me both the Request and Response headers?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, but I needed one additional line because of Java Spring framework on my internal application.

Here's the whole solution as a proxy file:

```
<Location /outside-app>
    # WEBSOCKET
    Header always add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*"
    ProxyPass wss://internal.company.com:11111/application

    RewriteEngine on
    Require all granted
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* https://internal.company.com:11111/application/$1 [P,L]

    # REVERSE PROXY
    ProxyPass https://internal.company.com:11111/application
    ProxyPassReverse https://internal.company.com:11111/application
</Location>
```