# Websocket rails in a SSL server with apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, websocket

I'm trying Websocket-rails to send messages from server to my client pages. Everything is ok until going to production in ssl mode.

I get this error in browser:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.com:3001/websocket' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I have a default configuration, only setting to stand alone mode.

config/initializers/websocket_rails.rb:

```
config.standalone = true
```

I did install redis server and start it without problems.

but when trying to connect, I get this error in log:

```
Invalid request: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.
    /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/request.rb:84:in `execute'
    /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/request.rb:84:in `parse'
    /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
    /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/faye-websocket-0.10.0/lib/faye/adapters/thin.rb:44:in `receive_data'
    /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/eventmachine-1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
    /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/eventmachine-1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
    /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
    /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
    /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:87:in `start'
    /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/websocket-rails-0.7.0/lib/rails/tasks/websocket_rails.tasks:14:in `block (3 $
    /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/websocket-rails-0.7.0/lib/rails/tasks/websocket_rails.tasks:13:in `fork'
    /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/websocket-rails-0.7.0/lib/rails/tasks/websocket_rails.tasks:13:in `block (2 $
    /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
    /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
    /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
    /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
    /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
    /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
```

Comment: Idk if this is of any use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468154/tunneling-secure-websocket-connections-with-apache

Comment: Does your client connect using a `wss://` prefix (instead of `ws://`)?