# Unable to connect to Websocket server over TLS

Tags: javascript, java, ssl, https, websocket

I have been testing the functionality of Websockets using a Javascript front-end and Java back-end. I have managed to get communication between client and server working on standard HTTP/WS protocols, but would like to enable HTTPS for serving up the front-end (website) and then use WSS for connecting to the server Java Endpoint.

So far I have setup the website with HTTPS/TLS using a self-signed certificate, and I am able to navigate to the website using the `HTTPS` protocol: "https://domain-name.chat".

Now I assumed it was just a matter of changing the protocol in the uri to `WSS` when establishing a new Websocket connection, so I changed the uri to "wss://domain.name.chat/serverEndpoint".

Now when I load the webpage the connection is not made, because it fires the Websocket.onclose() event handler.

I know there is nothing wrong with the code because it was previously working using HTTP/WS.

Am I right in understanding that Websockets doesn't have the issues of cross-domain script blocking?

Am I missing a step in the process of setting up HTTPS/WSS?

EDIT: Added Virtual host information for the website domain

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName domain-name.chat
    ServerAlias www.domain-name.chatt

    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/WebSocketChat/
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /WebSocketChat/$1 [l,PT]
    JkMount /* worker2

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

This is the connector setup in server.xml for Tomcat7:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="250" scheme="https" secure="true"
               keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Comment: Did you make proper changes on websocket server side? I.e. set up certificates, tls?

Comment: @Andrey Yes I  setup ssl and generating a self-signed certificate, and enabling virtual host SSLEngine with cert and key etc. Is TLS something seperate from SSL?

Comment: Tls is separate from ssl, but it's not problem related, since https can use both protocols for encryption. Also you're using apache as I can see, can you provide websocket related configuration, so we can diagnose what's wrong? May be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468154/tunneling-secure-websocket-connections-with-apache) question will help?

Comment: I have not attempted to reconfigure my server in anyway specific for Websockets, only for the SSL virtual host to allow website access  using https, where I assumed wss would just work.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using a self-signed certificate, there is a chance that the browser is refusing to connect even when everything is set up correctly.

For instance, my Safari browser will not connect to my self-signed certificate server (Iodine) while Chrome will.

I think Safari keeps checking the certificate Registry while Chrome doesn't (if you pass the warning screen)... It's browser specific.

**The Websocket protocol states that browsers should terminate the connection if the certificate isn't valid.**

as for:

> Am I right in understanding that Websockets doesn't have the issues of cross-domain script blocking?

It's not so simple and there is a minor security header that prevents cross-site scripting.

Although the security on this point is very easy to circumvent, browsers send the header `Origin` which states the original URL. When you try to connect to a Websocket on a different URL, the server is likely to refuse that connection unless it is set up to accept connections from any origin.

**Edit**: Another thought, brought on by the comments, is that your server might not be set up properly. Did you connect to the clear-text websocket server directly or using apache? for apache to proxy Websockets, some adjustments need to be made (search for [mod_websocket](https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=21767) ).