# ws_tunnel Apache->Websocket server not working

Tags: apache, websocket

I have a local web socket server running on WSS:// port 9000. In the same server I have apache running as well.

When I try and connect from my remote client directly to port 9000 via WSS like this:

`wss://myserver:9000`

it works fine. However, I blocked port 9000 on my router and am trying to access it via apache (which is running on SSL).

When I try and access 
`wss://myserver/`

I can see the logs in Apache that it issued a GET but my web socket server does not receive the connection.

I've read through various SO threads and I think I have my ordering correct.

Details:

Apache Version:
`Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)`

sudo apache2ctl -M shows proxy_* modules running

`proxy_module (shared)
proxy_http_module (shared)
proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)`

Apache configuration: (relevant lines inside VirtualHost)

```
ProxyPass / wss://localhost:9000/
ProxyPassReverse / wss://localhost:9000/

<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

Note that both my local web socket server and Apache are configured to use the same certificates

(I'm not sure if I need the Proxy * part, but I saw it in one SO thread)

And here are debug logs:

http://pastebin.com/gqVp3Pz5

Thanks

Comment: I have no idea about Apache setup for `ws`, but, I was wondering if it could be an SSL issue... does the `wss` service have a unique certificate (this could prevent a browser from connecting, unless that certificate is valid)? .... Did you try different browsers? Are you accessing the `wss` from an `https` webpage with the _same_ certificate (could be a mix&match issue)?

Comment: Thanks Myst, it looks like the module does not allow and end to end SSH tunnel between the local process and the remote client.

Answer (score 1):

It seems by default Apache wstunnel does not work when the need is to tunnel SSL end to end. What works is if Apache terminates WSS and then does a WS with the local server.

I found this thread [tunneling secure websocket connections with apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468154/tunneling-secure-websocket-connections-with-apache) that describes how to recompile Apache to allow for end to end WSS tunneling.

I've currently decided to not do apache tunneling and open a firewall port for my event server directly as I don't expect my users to have the inclination to recompile Apache for this.